# No ACK from established TCP connection

Tags: networking, tcp

This question was posted on StackExchange - NetworkEngineering. People suggested me to post it here. Here is my original post.

I am trying to write a client that initiates a TCP connection and sends some data. On the server side, I am using `nc` that listens to a certain port. Now I am able to complete the 3-way handshaking. `netstats` shows that the connection is established. However, after my client starts sending data, it never gets an ACK.

The client is implemented on top of DPDK, and thus bypasses the kernel stack. The server binds to a different NIC. The two NICs are directly connected. The TCP part is handled by my own code. Due to the lack of knowledge, the implementation is greatly simplified in the sense that I set a lot of fields to some fixed numbers, such as the window size.

As a newbie in networking, I have no clue what could go wrong, and thus not sure what information I should provide to help you identify the problem. Here is a screenshot from `wireshark`. My client is at `192.168.0.10:12345` and my server listens at `192.168.0.42:3456`. No ACK is sent from the server side after packet 6.

[image: Screenshot from <code>wireshark</code> after 3-way handshaking]

Also, the reason for the incorrect FCS is that I had to pad zeros to the SYN and the first ACK packets, so that they are at least 64 bytes, which is a requirement from the client NIC.

I did a comparison between packets from my client and packets from `nc` client. It seems that for the first data packet, the only real difference is that mine does not have any TCP options, while the `nc` one carries a timestamp. Could this be the problem?

Please let me know if you spot anything that may cause this no-ACK issue.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are expecting an ACK. After the normal TCP handshake no packets with an actual payload are sent (`Len=0` on all packets) so there is nothing to ACK. What is strange instead that the client is sending some ACK for some 9 bytes of data from the server where the data from the server don't show up in the packet capture.

Comment: Hi Steffen, thanks for your reply. After the 3-way handshake, my client was trying to send two packets (6 and 7 in the figure), each with 8 bytes of payload. I expected to see some ACK from the server, but apparently it did not happen. For those two packets, I set the PSH flag, hoping that the data will be delivered to the `nc` server rather than buffered somewhere. Also, for these two packets, the ACK flag was set since I learned that every packet after SYN should have their ACK flags set.

Comment: You are right. I must have been kind of blind to see the `Len=8` as `Len=0`. With `Len=8` the summary from Wireshark actually looks fine so the error is probably somewhere in the details of the packets which are not shown. Have you checked if the packets actually arrive at the recipients side because otherwise no ACK will be generated.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, the screenshot was from the server (i.e., the recipient) side. I think the packets do reach the server. My guess is that probably there are something wrong with my packet details, which causes the PSH-ACK packets being dropped by the TCP layer. But I am not sure how to identify such kind of problems.

Comment: *"...probably there are something wrong with my packet details... But I am not sure how to identify such kind of problems."* - a good start would be to actually look at the packet details. For now you only show a summary of the packets. For example providing the full packet capture (for example at cloudshark.org) would be a good idea to get more help.